# Kentico 8 - Localization with url prefixes - default document

Tags: c#, .net, content-management-system, kentico

I'm trying to follow the documentation page below to Use language prefixes for URLs

https://docs.kentico.com/display/K8/Configuring+URLs+for+multilingual+websites

I got a page with the alias "Home" that should be the default document for all the cultures.

three cultures are currently available:

- French (France) (Default)
- French (Belgium)
- Dutch (Belgium)

what i want to achieve is the following:

- [baseurl] -> redirect to [baseurl]/fr-fr/
- [baseurl]/fr-fr/ -> show just the page with "Home" alias
- [baseurl]/fr-be/ -> redirect to [baseurl]/fr-be/
- [baseurl]/nl-be/ -> redirect to [baseurl]/nl-be/

all of those should display the page with "Home" alias in the desired culture.

what I currently got instead is:

- [baseurl] -> redirect to [baseurl]/fr-fr/Home  CORRECT, but with wrong url ("Home" should not be necessary)
- [baseurl]/fr-fr/ -> show just the page with "Home" alias CORRECT
- [baseurl]/fr-be/ -> show the page with "Home" alias with French (France) culture
- [baseurl]/nl-be/ -> show the page with "Home" alias with French (France) culture

basically, is ignoring the url-prefix.

**MY SETUP**

1) got a page under the root with alias "Home" (which should be default) localized with all 3 cultures

2) in Settings/Content in the section "Web site content", "Default alias path" is set to "/Home".

3) in Settings/Urls & Seo in the section "SEO - Cultures" the values are the following:

- Force domain culture: FALSE
- Use language prefix for URLs: TRUE
- Allow URLs without language prefixes: FALSE

Am I doing something wrong? do I need to setup the website differently in order to let this work as expected?

Thanks

**ADDITONAL INFORMATION ABOUT THE BEHAVIOUR**

additional test cases about the weird behaviour of the site:

- [baseurl]/home-fr -> redirects to /fr-be/home
- [baseurl]/home-nl -> redirects to /nl-be/home

both of these seems ok, BUT both are displaying (french France) culture

- [baseurl]/fr-be/home-fr showing correctly the french Belgian version
- [baseurl]/nl-be/home-nl showing correctly the dutch Belgian version.

the problem is that it should use just the url alias "home", just like the normal fr-fr version. this alias is specified under the Url tab of the page:
[image: url setup on page]

**CURRENT SETTING**

Following you can find the page that I want to be default. Bear in mind that “Use custom URL path” was set to false, but for test purposed I turned that on, trying to associate /Home for all the cultures. Problem is that as soon as I save the path becomes “/Home-1”. I think this is because the default version of Home has already the Path “/Home”.

[image: Page I want as homepage]

**SETTINGS UNDER CONTENT**
Bear in mind here that I tried to use a macro to choose “Default alias path” in a different way depending on the culture. It didn’t work as it didn’t process the macro at all (the site was redirected to the literal string of the macro)

[image: content settings]

**SETTINGS UNDER URL & SEO**
Here I tried to check the “Use name path for URL path” option, but still no luck. (tried [baseurl]/nl-be and still shows the fr-fr version of the Homepage)
[image: settings url & seo 1]
[image: settings url & seo 2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ANSWER FROM KENTICO SUPPORT**

steps that I took to solve the problem:

1) under Url and Seo/Default page : select "Use domain root"

2) for each culture of the homepage > "Page URL Path", check "Use custom url path" and set "Path or pattern" to empty string ("")

now everything works as expected.

[domainname]/ > correctly redirects to [domainname]/fr-fr showing fr-fr culture

[domainname]/fr-fr > correctly shows fr-fr culture homepage

[domainname]/fr-BE > correctly shows fr-BE culture homepage

[domainname]/nl-BE > correctly shows nl-BE culture homepage

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest to go thru this article [cultures demystified](http://markerstudio.com/technical/2009/11/kentico-cultures-demystified) (for version 7, but the settings are still there) It's possible you are forcing a visitor culture on the site (Sites application)/user (Users application) settings, also enable the kentico SQL debug and check which culture is retrieved (in general which SQL queries are executed) based on the where condition...this could be an indication of what's going on...try also logging in as a different user and try different browsers (browsers have preferred language settings based on which kentico decides the displayed culture)

Make also sure you haven't setup aliases / page paths on the home page for specific cultures.

Comment: Default content culture is set "French (France)" but "Visitor Culture" is set to Automatic. I've also tried to use different browsers and clear cookies/use incognito mode.

for now what i've find out is that i can access other versions of the same page using /Home-fr (French Belgian) and /Home-nl (Dutch Belgian). those urls are specified on the "Page URL Path" section of the "Url" Tab. 

The problem is that that textbox is not editable and the check above "Use custom URL path" is unchecked. i don't know why i cannot reach with the same url different cultures by simply add the correct prefixes.

Comment: You will be able to edit the textbox if you check the "Use custom URL path" checkbox. Since you have the "Allow URLs without language prefixes: FALSE" setting, the system will always use the language prefixes. Frankly, I am a bit confused on what you want to achieve, could you please list all the cases with examples, e.g. <domain>/en-us/home should redirect to ... <domain>,  <domain>/es-es/home to <domain>/home-es and list all cases?

Comment: There might another setting which might be helpful for you:  URLs and SEO > SEO - URLs
Redirect page aliases to main URL. This will force a redirection to the main URL (=to the NodeAliasPath) or to the Page Url path if specified.(this behavior can be also specified on page aliases)

Comment: I'd also recommend you to look into wildcards, as they are a bit more flexible. Also remember that all settings (e.g. the  URLs and SEO > Page URLs > Default URL path prefix: ) can be initialized via a macro, so you can generate the prefixes you need this way as well.

Comment: I've added a few details about my settings above.
Allow URLs without language prefixes was already set to false. additionally, I tried to change default URL path prefix to the following macro "{% "/Home" + (Cookies["CMSPreferredCulture"]  == "fr-fr" ? "" : Cookies["CMSPreferredCulture"].SubString(0,2))%}", but it wasn't recognized as macro (in fact the website tried to redirect me to the literal string.

Comment: Ok, talked with support on kentico and find out a way to achieve this.
two main changes to the settings:

1) Url & seo > Default Page > Use domain root
2) for each version of the Homepage check "use custom url path" and put Empty string ("") to "Path or Pattern". now the system behaves correctly to the following cases:


- [domain]/ > redirect to /fr-fr and show fr-fr culture
- [domainname]/fr-fr > show fr-fr culture
- [domainname]/fr-BE > show fr-BE culture
- [domainname]/nl-BE> show nl-BE culture

Answer (score 1):

I had  the same problem, but I needed domain.com as main url for en-gb culture and for other domain.com/fr-fr and etc. And I couldn't find out of box solution, so I developed a custom module which catches events when TreeNode element is updated or created, and I update DocumentUrlPath column of current node with value "/" +culture code (or alias if it exists) + "/" + Current Document Name.
And I check if the currect document is home page, I save it without document name.
Also I untick from checkbox "Use prefixes for URLs" in settings.

Now everything works perfect on my site.

Comment: Thanks for your response.I was thinking to develop a custom functionality but I tried to avoid that. eventually I've found a new solution with the support from kentico.

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup also in settings Urls and SEO > SEO - URLs > Default page as Use domain root

Comment: Unfortunately I still have the same behaviour, except from the first case that now is correctly redirected to  [baseurl]/fr-fr/.
no help on other cases, still show the French (France) homepage regardless of the prefix.

Comment: Did you setup the aliases in Localization > Cultures  for French (Belgium) and for Dutch (Belgium) ?

Comment: Do you have translated all versions of Home page ? In settings > Content >Multilingual > Combine with default culture set to FALSE ?

Comment: no improvements. I still got the french version, even with changing the settings "Combine with default culture" to FALSE. 

Localization -> Cultures -> culture alias changes the URL prefix for each culture. is not related.

Comment: Don't you have domain aliases like in the documentation ? If you have try to remove Default alias path https://docs.kentico.com/download/attachments/4621045/Domain_Alias_Culture.png?version=1&modificationDate=1393920531294&api=v2
another way is to try without language prefixes and try with parameter ?lang=fr-be  if it will be working it mean thast the aliases doesn't work

Comment: the Default alias path is already empty. tried to remove the prefix and add ?lang=nl-BE and it doesn't work either. it's strange as definitively the page is translated in other cultures.